# Por que meu "try" em Python não funciona?

Tags: python, conversão-de-tipo

```py
x = int(input("Por favor, insira um número: "))
try:
    print(x != int)
except ValueError:
    print("Somente números.")
```

O erro que dá é:

> `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'`

Não sei o que fazer para que o Python me dê uma mensagem de erro quando o usuário der algo diferente de número como informação.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `try` serve exatamente para isso, para lançar uma exceção sua sem necessariamente parar o programa, porém, o modo que esta tentando utilizar esta incorreto, a linha que lança a exceção deve esta dentro do `try`

No seu caso você começa tentando atribuir um valor a `x` utilizando o `input`, até ai beleza, mas você quer converter ele a um numero inteiro usando o `int` e caso de se digitado algo que nao seja possível converter a um numero inteiro ele lança a exceção

Para corrigir esse problema você pode utlizar o `try`, mas lembrando, tem que esta dentro do mesmo, por exemplo

```
try:
    x = int(input("Por favor, insira um número: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Somente números.")
```

Pelo que entendi você quis colocar uma condição para o erro, porém, o `try` nao utiliza condição e sim quando um erro é lançado

### Bonus

Caso queira lança um erro usando condição utilize o `assert`

Um exemplo utilizando ele com o seu código, lembrando que é um exemplo com o seu código, mas o melhor método é o de cima

```
x = input("Por favor, insira um número: ")
try:
    assert x.isnumeric() and x.isascii()  # O método "isascii()" funciona somente para as versões mais recentes do Python, porém, o uso dela seria para restringir a quantidade de caracteres para o determinado exemplo, para versões desatualizadas, pode fazer o uso de "ord()" no lugar dos dois.
    # assert all([ord(d) in range(48, 58) for d in x])  # Para versões anteriores há essa opção onde irá restringir os números de 0 a 9
except:
    print("Somente números.")
else:
    x = int(x)
```

Comment: Só lembrando que há vários caracteres para os quais `isnumeric` retorna `True` mas dão erro ao converter para `int`, [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/BjUfXE). No fim a melhor opção mesmo é a primeira: usar logo `int()` e capturar o `ValueError`

Comment: Sim e concordo, como disse acima a primeira é mais valida, porem, o código do rapaz, se você analisar verá que ele tentou usar uma condição, algo que o __try__ não utiliza e só quis mostra como funciona quando você quer usar condição para retornar uma exceção, é apenas um demonstração e ensinamento de como o __try__ e o __assert__ funciona

Comment: Mas agradeço a observação, irei corrigir restringindo um pouco mais os caracteres para esse exemplo, porém, infelizmente será valido para as versões mais recentes do Python que agora não me recordo qual versão exatamente

Answer (score 8):

Você pede o dado e tenta fazer a conversão (a função `int()` faz isto), e se a conversão não for possível (porque o texto digitado não é satisfatório para criar um número inteiro) uma exceção será lançada (infelizmente a documentação é falha e não fala nada sobre isto). Se deseja fazer algo quando isto ocorre então deve capturar a exceção como o fez no `except`, porém a captura só ocorrerá em códigos que estejam dentro do bloco `try`, o que não era o caso, então quando a exceção é lançada não há captura e a aplicação quebra. Assim faz o que deseja:

```
try:
    print(int(input("Por favor, insira um número: ")))
except ValueError:
    print("Somente números.")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/a3Ynj8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/TryIntConversionpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/TryIntConversion.py).

E pra ficar claro, o Python está dando exatamente uma mensagem de erro quando o usuário digita algo diferente de um número. O que deseja é justamente o oposto, quer que o seu código dê uma mensagem sua quando isto ocorrer e não o Python.

Answer (score -3):

Vincenslau se você deseja guardar o valor do input na variável x faça da seguinte forma:

```
while True:
    x = input("Por favor, insira um número: ")
    try:
        x = int(x)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Somente números.")
```

e Feliz ano novo...

Comment: Por que usar while seria melhor?

Comment: Estou deduzindo que, se "o programa " está imprimindo uma mensagem ("Somente números.") então o usuário provavelmente deverá entrar com um outro valor, que seja valido, novamente e é isso que o while faz, mais se quiser, pode tirar o while e o break e código vai funcionar também.

Comment: Tá, mas isso ai não foi explicado na resposta, é o mesmo que uma pessoa que vende "sabão em pó" dizer que a marca dele é a melhor porque limpa melhor ... isso não fala nada tecnicamente, claro que a maioria das pessoas são preguiçosas e gostam de só ouvir "usa isso que funciona melhor" sem saber o porque supostamente é melhor. Se somos uma comunidade de programadores temos que explicar os pontos e os "porques" para que a resposta possa ensinar a programar e para que não seja mais um código de "copie e cole que vai funcionar".

Comment: É o típico caso de desentendimento e falta de boa fé ao entender um comparativo simples, sabão em pó é um exemplo para exemplificar o problema, geralmente quem não gosta de comparativos para exemplificar algo é que tem problemas em aceitar criticas construtivas, foi o que eu fiz, lhe dei um compartivo, vc deve ter boa vontade e entender que algo precisa ser melhorado e que não somos um site de suporte técnico e nem de ctrl+c, somos um site que buscamos ensinar a programar, no teu comentário vc explicou os "porques" falta explicar na pergunta, então coloque o seu ego de lado e aceite uma dica.

Comment: **ps:** os downvotes não são meus, mas se apenas acrescentar teu comentário no CORPO da RESPOSTA, usando o botão editar vou lhe dar +1 como sinal de boa fé de minha parte, para ficar contra o downvote q recebeu. Como já disse, são criticas construtivas, se cê considera um bom dev e quer evoluir deve aceita-las ou no minimo analisar para ter certeza que você pode ou não melhorar em certos pontos, seja como pessoa, seja como profissional, seja como programador.

Comment: Entendo o ponto e vista do @Guilherme Nascimento e concordo com ele, sua reposta nao esta incorreta, esta correta e funcionando, então é uma reposta valida e nao merece os downvotes, porém, o que ele esta tentando dizer é simplesmente para melhorarmos as nossas repostas para que sirvam para os demais e ajude o aprendizado, evitando que crie conteudo de copia e cola, algo que tbm discordo muito. A unica coisa que ele esta orientando é que se crie conteúdo explicativo e não apenas passe a reposta

Comment: Como muitos se comenta, o próprio código em python já é autoexplicativo e ainda mais em pequeno código como este. Fui....

Comment: Muitos então comentam errado o autoexplicativo, uma coisa é as "APIs" nativas e sintaxes da lingaguem serem compreensiva, outra coisa são os algoritmos" criados com códigos, então quem comentou ou comentou errado sobre ser autoexplicativo ou comentou sobre a "sintaxe da linguagem" e não sobre os algoritmos escritos com a tal linguagem e você compreendeu errado o que eles queriam dizer sobre "autoexplicativo".

Comment: O código pode até ser "autoexplicativo" **pra quem já conhece a linguagem**. Mas pela pergunta dá pra ver que a pessoa não conhece (e nada de errado com isso, afinal é por isso que ela perguntou). E como a pessoa não conhece, então uma explicação, por mais simples que seja, se faz necessária (veja as outras respostas, por exemplo).

Comment: Eu estou com vontade de dar upvote nessa resposta mas não posso. Falta a explicação do porque do uso do `while` para conhece lógica de programação faz sentido, mas para quem esta começando e vem de uma pesquisa google e aterriza de paraquedas aqui não é muito intuitivo.